# Is it possible to have a Ember.TEMPLATES proxy?

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm developing an app with `Ember 1.0.rc3` and I'm loading my precompiled `Handlebars` template files from my backend server *on demand* via `Ajax` requests. To be able to handle this, I created my own template manager, which is pulling the templates from the server and stores them in `Ember.TEMPLATES`.

Now, this is working pretty good, but for the sake of lazyness I wonder if there is a possibility to hook into some code within the `Ember` framework and put my template manager as a proxy in front so that every time when Ember does it's magic, its doing this by accessing my manager first?

EDIT:

Here's some code, basically my template manager is just a class, which - as I said - loads the precompiled templates from the server and places them into the `Ember.TEMPLATES` template cache.

```
fetchTemplate: function (templateName, templateAlias) {
    var alias = templateAlias || templateName;

    var retString = '';

    // check if the template already exists
    if (typeof Ember.TEMPLATES[alias] === 'undefined') {
      // create the ajax request object

      $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        data: { templateName: templateName },
        url: 'template/request',
        success: function(data) {
          if (typeof data.template === 'string' && data.template !== '') {

            var escapedTemplateString =
                data.template.replace(/\\n/g, "\\n").replace(/\\r/g, "\\r").replace(/\\t/g, "\\t");

            escapedTemplateString = escapedTemplateString.replace(/\s+/g, " ");

            // load the template into the Ember.TEMPLATES template cache
            Ember.TEMPLATES[alias] = Ember.Handlebars.template(eval("(" + escapedTemplateString + ")"));

            retString = alias;
          } else {
            retString = '';
          }
        }
      });
    } else {
      retString = alias;
    }

    return retString;

  },

releaseCache: function() {
  Ember.TEMPLATES = {};
}
```

Comment: How does your Templates manager look like, code?

Comment: @intuitivepixel please see my edited question for the code of my template manager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implementing a custom resolver (or subclassing the default resolver) would let you tap into Ember's process for finding templates. However, I don't think you would be able to successfully integrate your approach because resolving is expected to be synchronous.

Comment: I see, thanks. If I'll add the `async: true` flag to my `$.ajax` object it should be synchronous, am I right? How _save_ is it (in terms of upgrade conflicts from rc3 upwards) to subclass the default resolver?

Comment: Yes, that would work, but would be a pretty bad idea for performance, IMO. Your UI would be unresponsive while those ajax requests are made. What problem are you trying to solve with this style of template loading? In terms of API stability, per http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.DefaultResolver.html "The methods of this object are designed to be easy to override in a subclass." The team is supporting this as public API.

Comment: thx for  your answer! I'm implementing this form of template loading, because the web app should support a lot of languages with a really big bunch of internationalization (resource files) where each has ~ 40,000 entries at least. also the web app needs a whole lot of templates in the end (I guess there will be more then 200), but it should be 'responsive' and be available for mobile devices also. If I would pack all of these in one big `application.js` it would be a too big file, and I won't load all of the i18n and template files, if only 10% of all is needed for one session.

Comment: @herom Sounds like a legitimate use case that Ember does not support well today. I would suggest opening an issue about this on the ember.js github.

Comment: I filed an issue over at `Ember.js` github. here's the link: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/2742